# Understanding get_misses in memaslap

Tags: memcached

I am trying to understand the behaviour of memcached by running memaslap against it.

The command I use is

```
 memaslap -s localhost:11212 -T 64 -c 64 --verbose -S 1s -t 30s
```

and this is the output I get (on local machine)

```
Get Statistics (3157196 events)
   Min:        36
   Max:     17957
   Avg:       545
   Geo:    533.99
   Std:    167.05
   Log2 Dist:
       4:        0        0       11      271
       8:     2813   1379137   1706845    66407
      12:     1110      446      152        4

Set Statistics (350829 events)
   Min:        60
   Max:     16184
   Avg:       547
   Geo:    536.33
   Std:    161.65
   Log2 Dist:
       4:        0        0        3       28
       8:      313   151210   191252     7861
      12:      112       40       10

Total Statistics (3508025 events)
   Min:        36
   Max:     17957
   Avg:       545
   Geo:    534.22
   Std:    167.17
   Log2 Dist:
       4:        0        0       14      299
       8:     3126   1530347   1898097    74268
      12:     1222      486      162        4

cmd_get: 3157252
cmd_set: 350837
get_misses: 1716802
written_bytes: 608669765
read_bytes: 1610227982
object_bytes: 381710656

Run time: 30.0s Ops: 3508089 TPS: 116914 Net_rate: 70.5M/s
```

As you can see I have get_misses which amount to 1716802, which is more than 50% of the get requests sent by memaslap. I am curious about what a get_miss means. I checked the docs at 
http://docs.libmemcached.org/bin/memaslap.html 
and plainly says

> get_misses
>
> How many objects can’t be gotten from server
>   What does it mean to not get a key from server? Is it because the key is not present or is it because of latencies? 
>   If its because the key is not present, what exactly is memaslap testing by sending this request?

Comment: Hello, I have a question related to running `memaslap` command. Did you manage to run it right after installing `libmemcached-dev` library?

Comment: hI @AnaKhorguani, yes. But not sure if SO comments section is the place to chat

Comment: Thank you. Yes, sorry I had the issue with running `memaslap` and I only found a very few discussions about it. That's why I commented.

Answer (score 1):

It says how many times we've got cache miss while running the get command, in other words - how many times key was not found.

The main reason why there are cache misses is **eviction**. Memcached throws some items out of memory to free space for the new ones.

Number of `get_misses` should drop if memcached would have more RAM to use (for instance: `-m 1G` for 1 Gb of RAM)